Is there a reason that the opening premise of DAIMA is the same as GT?
As I watched Dragon Ball DAIMA, the premise was very familiar.  "Evil guy turns Goku into a kid."  DAIMA goes a bit beyond that, de-aging the entire Dragon Ball crew.  But it still seemed odd that they would repeat the same plot device.  I know GT was not canon, so maybe the author wanted to show, "if you are going to do that, here's how it's done, son." ?

Probably they made the characters too powerful so they have to de-power them because they wouldnt have anything else to destroy. In the Buu saga they were already able to tear apart our dimension. In the Super Saga they had to fight in an arena built with the hardest material in the universe yet they still destroy it
